# how do I change my complex mysql query into mysql view

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I'm a nubie in mysql queries, and I would like to ask, whether if there's someone who can help me to solve my problem. I have this complex(for me) sql. and I want to change it into a view.

```
SELECT 
    username, 
    user_id,
    sum(result_points) AS count_points, 
    count(result_points) AS activity_done, 
    (
        (
            SELECT count(*) FROM `activity` WHERE periode_id = ''
        ) + 
        (
            SELECT
                IFNULL(sum(acs.result_points), 0) 
            FROM 
                user_activity ua 
            WHERE 
                periode_id = '' 
            AND ua.user_id = user_activity.user_id
            AND ua.result_points IS NOT NULL
        )
    ) AS total
    FROM 
        user_activity 
        LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = user_activity.user_id 
    WHERE 
        periode_id = '' 
    and user_id > 0 
    GROUP BY user_id 
    ORDER BY total DESC
```

is there a way, to take out the "where" statement,so that i still can change it to view?

Comment: Do you get any error while defining a view with this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you query is correct, create view like

```
Create View data as
SELECT 
    username, 
    user_id,
    sum(result_points) AS count_points, 
    count(result_points) AS activity_done, 
    (
        (
            SELECT count(*) FROM `activity` WHERE periode_id = ''
        ) + 
        (
            SELECT
                IFNULL(sum(acs.result_points), 0) 
            FROM 
                user_activity ua 
            WHERE 
                periode_id = '' 
            AND ua.user_id = user_activity.user_id
            AND ua.result_points IS NOT NULL
        )
    ) AS total
    FROM 
        user_activity 
        LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = user_activity.user_id 
    WHERE 
        periode_id = '' 
    and user_id > 0 
    GROUP BY user_id 
    ORDER BY total DESC
```

Remove where clause from view and add where clause in view, like

```
select * from data where user_id > 0
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Vinit, and im sorry that i post an ambigous sql. because the problem is, i also want the periode_id to be in where clause also. Not only the user_id. is it possible?

Comment: add periode_id as column and filter it in View as user_id